# check subscribe value and return it in canDeactivate

Tags: angular, rxjs

In canDeactivate guard I am subscribe to confirm service. Confirm component has 3 buttons and when one of them are clicked, it eject enum. How can I check value in subscribe to view, do smth and return boolean for guard depending on the value?

CanDeactivateGuard:

```
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
      constructor(private modalDialogService: ModalService) {
      }
      canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate,
                          route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (!component.isUnsavedChanges()) {
          return true;
        }
        this.modalDialogService.showConfirm(ConfirmType.CAN_DEACTIVATE).subscribe(val => {
             //here I want to check value, do some functions and return true/false
    })
          }
        }
```

ConfirmComponent:

```
export class ConfirmComponent {
      subject: Subject<ConfirmAction>;

      constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

      action(action: ConfirmAction):void {  //here the value of click
        this.bsModalRef.hide();
        this.subject.next(action);
        this.subject.complete();
      }
    }

    export enum ConfirmAction {
      SAVE,
      REVERT,
      CANCEl,
    }
```

ModalService:

```
export class ModalService {

  constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService,
              private ts: TranslatorService) {}

  public showConfirm(modalDialogType: ConfirmType, extraInfo?: string): Observable<ConfirmAction> {
    let modal;
    switch (modalDialogType) {
      case ConfirmType.CAN_DEACTIVATE: {
        modal = this.bsModalService.show(ConfirmComponent, config);
        break;
      }
/*
other cases
*/
return modal.content.subject.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

canDeactivate is waiting for an Observable, you can do something like this :

```
      canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate,
                          route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (!component.isUnsavedChanges()) {
          return true;
        }
        return this.modalDialogService.showConfirm(ConfirmType.CAN_DEACTIVATE).pipe(
            map(val => {
               // Here, do your work and return true or false
            })
        )
      }
```

Take a look at the Rxjs documentation https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

I hope it will help you !